# Using Sass rails in elastic-beanstalk

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, sass, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app that depends on sass to do some of the formatting.

It works locally, but when I try to move it to elastic beanstalk it fails to load the gem..

How do it run to command

```
bundle exec sass -Ibower_components -Iscss --watch scss/brand_oit_appdev.scss:css/brand_oit_appdev.css
```

before eb deploys the server.